# Custom friendship model or Amistad gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Am I better off building a custom friendship model or should I implement amistad? If Amisad, are there any issues with it. Like features that dont necessarily work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the functionality you're trying to achieve.

To be completely frank, gems like Amistad typically don't end up saving you much time, especially if you end up needing to expand on the Gem.  Were it me, I would sketch out a wish list of friend features, and see if Amistad could provide a substantial foundation (say, doing 90% of the work for me).  In most situations, you're probably better off rolling your own solution.  That way, you'll never be limited by a Gem that doesn't bring that much to the table in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Amistad for the first time here and I think it's sweet, it's so minimal... The "dont reinveint the wheel" instinct rings too, why build it from scratch? I don't want to be checking my whole implementation if a dude already did this before! :P It also leaves the door open for contributing and etc...

So, I reached the point where I wanted to extend Amistad functionality, more precisely, create mailboxer notifications when inviting and I followed a nice little pattern I discovered in [Null Object Pattern for associations in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121737/null-object-pattern-for-associations-in-rails/15508169#15508169)

Basically:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Amistad::FriendModel

  module AmistadExtension
    def invite(user)
    p "works!"
    super
  end

  include AmistadExtension
end
```

Now in `rails c`:

```
> p = Profile.first
> p.invite p # this returns false because it's sending friend request to itself
"works!"
false
```

Don't know if this can solve everything that I'll need, but it's saving me time.