# Null Object Pattern for associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, null-object-pattern

Despite looking at a few answers here regarding Null Objects in rails, I can't seem to get them to work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  def profile
    self.profile || NullProfile #I have also tried
    @profile || NullProfile #but it didn't work either
  end
end

class NullProfile
  def display #this method exists on the real Profile class
    ""
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    User.new(params)
  end
end
```

My problem is that on User creation, I pass in the proper nested attributes (profile_attributes) for the Profile and I end up with a NullProfile on my new User.

I am guessing that this means that my custom profile method is getting called on create and returning a NullProfile. How do I do this NullObject properly so that this only happens on read and not on the initial creation of the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going exactly through and I wanted a clean new object if it wasn't present(if you're doing this just so `object.display` doesn't err maybe `object.try(:display)` is better) this too and this is what I found:

1: alias/alias_method_chain

```
def profile_with_no_nill
  profile_without_no_nill || NullProfile
end
alias_method_chain :profile, :no_nill
```

But since alias_method_chain is being deprecated, if you're staying on the edge you would have to do the pattern by yourself manually... [The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689736/rails-3-alias-method-chain-still-used) seems to provide the better and more elegant solution

2(Simplified/practical version from the answer):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  module ProfileNullObject
    def profile
      super || NullProfile
    end
  end
  include ProfileNullObject
end
```

**note:** The order you do this matter(explained in the linked answer)

---

On what you tried:

When you did

```
def profile
  @profile || NullProfile
end
```

It won't behave as expected because the Association is lazily loaded(unless you told it to `:include` it in the search), so @profile is nil, that's why you're always getting NullProfile

```
def profile
  self.profile || NullProfile
end
```

It will fail because the method is calling itself, so it's sort like a recursive method, you get `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

Answer (score 2):

I've found a simpler option than including a private module in the accepted answer.

You can override the reader method and fetch the associated object using the `association` method from `ActiveRecord`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile

  def profile
    association(:profile).load_target || NullProfile
  end
end # class User
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using alias_method_chain, use this:

```
def profile
  self[:profile] || NullProfile.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rails [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Overriding+generated+methods), the association methods are loaded into a module, so it's safe to override them.

So, something like...

```
def profile
  super || NullProfile.new
end
```

Should work for you.