# Mongoid association & null object pattern?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, null-object-pattern

How would you implement the null object pattern on a Mongoid relation?

```
Class Owner
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :preference
end
```

Most owners won't have a preference, and thus I want them to have a NullPreference instead, as described in Ben Orenstein's [excellent talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DC-pQPq0acs).

What I would like is something like this:

```
class NullPreference
  def name
    'no name'
  end 
end

owner = Owner.new
preference = owner.preference
preference.name
=> 'no name'
```

I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121737/null-object-pattern-for-associations-in-rails) regarding the same thing in ActiveRecord, no answers though.

Edit: I'm using Mongoid 2.6 otherwise I could've used `autobuild: true` and get a *real* `Preference` and use the defaults instead.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious way is to build a layer of abstraction over that field.

```
class Owner
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :preference_field # internal field, don't use directly

  def preference
    preference_field || NullPreference.new
  end

  def preference= pref
    self.preference_field = pref
  end
end
```

Maybe there are simpler ways.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, that's certainly a possibility! But maybe there's a cleaner way.